Save a captcha image or take screenshot from website with VBA SeleniumBasic
I need to save a captcha image locally from a website but I haven't been able to do it. I have made some progress with my code but not completely.
I'm trying to take a screenshot of a website's numerical captcha. I have a code for it but although I manage to save an image, it does not correspond to the captcha but to a region that is higher than where the captcha is (the one it brings is not an image as such).
This part of the code is the one that comes close to what I require. However, it does not take the correct screenshot
    Dim element As WebElement
    
    Set element = bot.FindElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxRoundPanel3_Image2")
    
    
    ' Guarda la captura de pantalla como JPG
    element.TakeScreenshot.Save "C:\Users\DOGOOMEN\Pictures\imagene.jpg", 1 ' wdFormatJPEG

I appreciate you please help me solve it. I think I'm close to achieving it but I don't know how to position this required element (captcha image) better or somehow to save it.
